# For some reason my entire choropleth is gray. Using folium, a small dataframe, and a zip-code geojson from NYC

Tags: python, choropleth

I have a dataframe with zip codes in one column and the number of call center complaints in the other. I'm trying to create a choropleth which should be a simple one, but for some reason it keeps on showing up all gray.

I'm probably making a very simple small error, but I can't locate it. Any help would be appreciated

I have changed types of my data, tried some different key_on options, switched up columns.

```
!pip install folium
import folium

# create a plain world map
world_map = folium.Map(location=[40.7128, -74.0060], zoom_start=11, tiles='Mapbox Bright')

nyc_geo = r'nyc_zips.json' # geojson file


# generate choropleth map using the total immigration of each country to Canada from 1980 to 2013
world_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=nyc_geo,
    threshold_scale = [0,5000,10000,15000,20000,25000,30000,35000,40000],
    data=df_zip_codes,
    columns=['ZipCode', 'Complaints'],
    key_on='feature.properties.zips',
    fill_color= 'YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.5,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Complaints By Zip Code'
)

# display map
world_map
```

My dataframe looks like this. 189 rows total. ZipCode and Complaints type(int):

```
    ZipCode Complaints
0   11226   37452
1   10458   35107
2   10467   34272
3   10468   30858
4   10453   30763
5   10452   25279
...
```

And finally, this is the geoJSON file I am using:
http://data.beta.nyc//dataset/3bf5fb73-edb5-4b05-bb29-7c95f4a727fc/resource/6df127b1-6d04-4bb7-b983-07402a2c3f90/download/f4129d9aa6dd4281bc98d0f701629b76nyczipcodetabulationareas.geojson

I don't need this to do much other than be shaded based upon the number of complaints in each zip code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually just spotted my mistake. Was using the wrong label for the key_on property. It is postalCode in the geoJSON. Also changed  the of my zip code column to string and it is working fine.

Comment: Writing down the question is a helpful path towards solution.

Comment: It definitely was in this case.